# Rotating an arbitrary polygon around its own center

Tags: easeljs, createjs

I'm trying to find a way to rotate an arbitrary polygon around its own geometric center. It was drawn in a blackboard built with creating js.

I've been trying many approaches, but any of them has worked.

How can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 1):

Find the geometric centre as the average of all the points' coordinates. Make all the points relative to this centre (such that the centre is `(0,0)`), then rotate them by the desired angle using a [rotation matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RotationMatrix.html). You can then draw using these points.

This is assuming you have the coordinates of all the points.

Comment: Yes, you need to derive your center yourself, as there is no method for it in EaselJS. Once you do that, set the `regX` and `regY` to the center values, and just use the `rotation` property.

Comment: @Lanny Would an average of the points be the most suitable centre?

Comment: It really depends on your shape geometry. It is probably a good approach to get the general center point of a shape.